# Is there a way to stop a single docker service and remove its assigned volume(s)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was wondering (but search seems to indicate otherwise) if there is a docker command to stop a *single* service and remove its assigned volumes too. The equivalent of running:
1 - `docker-compose stop <service name>`
2 - `docker volume rm <volumes_attached_to_service>`

I don't mind if it removes the image for the service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer:

Based on your comment:

> I want to stop a single docker service and remove its assigned volumes.

This command should do the trick:

```
docker-compose rm -f -s -v <service>
```

or

```
docker-compose rm -fsv <service>
```

Where, `-f` will force and not ask for confirmation, `-s` will ensure the container is stopped before removing it, and `-v` will remove the volumes attached to the service.

Comment: I realised I should used better terminology. I want to stop a single docker service and remove its assigned volumes.

Comment: @DarkStar1 See my updated answer, it should be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

If the container is stopped but still exists, no. You have to delete all container using a volume before deleting said volume. Even using the `docker volume rm --force` would not do the trick.

I could not find a specific mention in the doc, but [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/521) discuss the lack of doc related to the subject and some workaround.

You can however stop **AND delete** a container with it's related volumes in certain situations:

- [`docker-compose down --volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) when all volumes to be deleted are listed in the `docker-compose.yml` file(s) used
- If using anonymous volumes, running the container with [`docker run --rm`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#remove-anonymous-volumes) or `docker-compose run --rm` will cause container and attached anonymous volumes to be deleted when container is stopped

In other situations you would have to remove the container and remove its volumes with separate commands.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't clarify that I wanted to stop a single service from the list of running services.